# how can I round the result of a procedure

Tags: java, function, rounding, procedure

I have to round the numbers of my result. It has to have to digits after the decimal point. One of them is a procedure and the other one is a function. ( I dont know if thats the right terminology in english I am german).

```
public class Distanz {

    //Prozedur 

    static double x1;
    static double y1;
    static double x2;
    static double y2;

    
    public static void berechneDistanzAlsProzedur ( double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2 ) {
    
        System.out.println("Distanz von p1 und p2 berechnet mit einer Prozedur:" + Math.sqrt((x1*x1-x2*x2)+(y1*y1+y2*y2)) + ".");
        //System.out.printf( "Distanz von p1 und p2 berechnet mit einer Prozedur:" + "%.2f" + ".", berechneDistanzAlsProzedur(10.0,8.0,2.0,12.0));
    }
 
    //Funktion

    public static double berechneDistanzAlsFunktion (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){

        return Math.sqrt((x1*x1+x2*x2)+(y1*y1+y2*y2));
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        berechneDistanzAlsProzedur(10.0,8.0,2.0,12.0); 
        //System.out.println("Distanz von p1 und p2 berechnet mit einer Funktion:" + berechneDistanzAlsFunktion(10.0,8.0,2.0,12.0) + ".");
        System.out.printf( "Distanz von p1 und p2 berechnet mit einer Funktion:" + "%.2f" + ".", berechneDistanzAlsFunktion(10.0,8.0,2.0,12.0)   );
    }
   // Math.round(cm2inch(number)*100)/100f
}
```

Comment: Is the code that you've posted not working? If so, what problems are you having with it?

Comment: Hello? Again, it looks like you're already doing what you want to be doing. Again, how is it not working?

Comment: no the code is properly working. But i dont know how i can round the result of my procedure.

Comment: By doing the exact same thing that you're doing in the second

Comment: you mean i have to write System.out.printf into the procedure

Comment: Best to try it and see what happens. Also, look into String.format(...)` which uses the same structure as printf but does not print a String but rather returns a formatted String